# How to get id value of a parent div in ng-model?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

For example I have this div element:

```
<div id="5000_1">
    <input type="text" ng-model="**PARENT_ID**.firstName" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" ng-model="**PARENT_ID**.lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
</div>
```

How to make ng-model to take the id of parent div?

Comment: Use this "$parent.firstName" if you have subNodes  "$parent.$parent.firstName"

Answer (score -1):

This is probably the wrong way to go about it.  You are basically asking how to dynamically create scope variables (because ng-model binds to a scope variable).

If you want to uniquely identify first/last names based on parent id then you should be converting this code snippet into a directive.

```
angular.module('mainModule', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {'=parentid'},
      template: '<div>' +
        '<input type="text" ng-model="firstname" placeholder="First Name">' +
        '<input type="text" ng-model="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">' +
        '</div>',
      link: function (scope) {
            //Functions to do what you want here.
            }
    };
  });
```

Then put it on the page like so:

```
<my-directive parentid="1234">
```

This will pass the parent id into your directive's scope to do what you want with it.

Comment: Yes it is kind of building scope variable dynamically. Do you have an idea of how directive should look like?